# Separating an argument string into double java

Tags: java

So I'm trying to develop a method using `String.split` and `Double.parseDouble` and i really need some help! I am relatively new to programming. I'm using Java.

Anyhow, this method interprets a sequence of numbers separated by commas to produce an array of Strings, then it parses each of the strings to get a double, then stores them in sequence.

So far I've managed to separate the String arguments into individual lines:

```
public class Sequence
{
...
     public Sequence(String a)
     { 
          for (String returnvalue: s.split(",")){
          System.out.println(returnvalue);
     }
     }
...
}
```

At this point i am just so lost! However i do have each of the Strings seperated into individual lines. From here i just have to use the parser to convert the Strings into Doubles and store them in sequence.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Also, does anyone know where i could learn more about Java programming? I am stuck for resources.

Comment: create double array and fill it with `Double.parseDouble(returnvalue);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the `split()` method returns an array. You're looping through it fine, so all you need to do is parse each string into a double for each loop iteration to get an array of doubles:

```
String[] tokens = s.split(",");
double[] result = new double[tokens.length];
int i = 0; // This is used for putting each double in the array
for(String token:tokens) {
    result[i++] = Double.parseDouble(token);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! You guys must have so much instantaneous knowledge, it must feel great. Thank you for your time!

Comment: Yo! So i've been working through more code and i decided to use this example above ^

String[] tokens = s.split(",");
double[] result = new double[tokens.length]; 
int i = 0; 
         for(String token:tokens){ 
 result[i++] = Double.parseDouble(token);
                               }
     
But the value for tokens that it's giving me is insane! I input a variable for string s such as... "2,3,4" and it displays code like this:
2
3
4
tokens[Ljava.lang.string;@11d2e1e] 

etc.

I used println to see what values were actually being assigned.

@APerson

Comment: Also i realise that code isn't showing in comments, but it is the same as the answer you listed above @APerson

Comment: @Lang_lang You're probably passing the array directly into the println method. If you want to print out each array element, you can just loop through the array: `for(double d:result) System.out.println(d);`

Comment: Ah yes i fixed it all :) it now displays all the array values i want. I ended up using Arrays.toString(token) etc. and now it's perfect! Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Create List like:

```
String[] array = a.split(",");
List<Double> doubleList = new ArrayList<>(array.length);
for (String token : array) {
    doubleList.add(Double.valueOf(token));
}
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer this question! i really appreciate it!